# My describe-load-balancers query does not return a full list Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-cli

When I run the following command:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].LoadBalancerName'
```

I only get 19 Load Balancers in the output even though I have over 200 in my account. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 14):

Need to use `aws elbv2` instead of `aws elb` because `elb` only pulls Classic Load Balancers.

See: [elbv2 — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerName'
```

This will give you a list of all the loadbalancers